# A collection of the finite subsets of an infinite set is not a sigma-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Show that if $\Omega$ is an infinite set then $\mathcal{A} = \{A\subset\Omega : A \text{  is  finite}\}$ is NOT a sigma-algebra.

---

This seems easy but I found myself confused. Here's what I figured out. Let $a_n\in \Omega$ be an infinite sequence in $\Omega$. Consider the set $\{a_n, a_{n+1}\}$ which is finite and therefore in $\mathcal{A}$.

Now consider $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \{a_n, {a_{n+1}}\} = \{a_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

The set should be in $\mathcal{A}$ because it is a union of sets in $\mathcal{A}$ but isn't because it is an infinite set and therefore $\mathcal{A}$ is not a sigma-algebra.

**1. Is this correct?**

**2. Is there a simpler solution?**

Comment: Why $\{a_n,a_{n+1}\}$ instead of just $\{a_n\}$?  Also, what about the complement of $\{a\}$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer No particular reason. I guess I just visualised it that way. And yes, the complement of $\{a\}$ would be infinite and would be an easier proof, thanks.

Comment: Oh I guess I should answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, only to me it seems strange to use $\{a_n,a_{n+1}\}$ when $\{a_n\}$ works with the same result.  Maybe it is just me, but this could make the reader take an extra few seconds wondering why that was done.
2. Yes, because if $B$ is a finite subset of $\Omega$, then $\Omega\setminus B$ is infinite and not in $\mathcal A$.  E.g., taking $B=\varnothing$, $\Omega$ is not in $\mathcal A$ although its complement is.